# Date Formatting like Date Picker in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, datepicker, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2014

I'm using reporting service.

How can I set date to be formatted like, we manually select date using date picker.

I want a textbox should be formatted like below image on tab click.

[image]

*Please help me. Thanks in advance!*

Comment: Where do you show the report to users? On SSRS web portal, or using ReportViewer control?

Comment: Using report viewer control

Comment: You could have two parameters. Parameter 1 is a string and you use MID to pass a default value to the date control.  i.e.  =MID(Parameters!Datestring.value,1,2) & "/" & MID(Parameters!Datestring.value,3,2) & "/" & MID(Parameters!Datestring.value,5,4)

Comment: Just to clarify - is it WinForms control or ASP.NET control?

Comment: ASP.NET control...